# How to read a DNA sequence from a text File and store it in an array in C?

Tags: bioinformatics, dna-sequence

How to read a DNA sequence from a text File in C language and store it in an array and extract all the substrings of a given length starting from each nucleotide position?

For Example the sequence is in the following way in the text file

> cctgatagacgctatctggctatccaggtacttaggtcctctgtgcgaatctatgcgtttccaaccat

All the substrings of all the starting positions

if length of the sub string = 3

cct, ctg, tga, gat, ..., cat

Comment: parse fasta/fastq files with this: http://lh3lh3.users.sourceforge.net/parsefastq.shtml it's very handy.

Answer (score 0):

Is C language compulsory to you?

I would move to a higher level language such as Python, this function would do:

```
from itertools import count

def iterate_fragments(sequence,size):
    """Takes a string and yields pieces of given size."""
    for number in count():
        try: yield sequence[number:number+size]
        except IndexError: break

for fragment in iterate_fragments(dna_sequence,3):
    print fragment
```

This simple code will print each dna fragment (3 nucleotides size).